# POSTing JSON Object to server using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I have tried to send a JSON object to server, from my android App but it doesn't seem to work. There is no error present, but it also doesn't send any data to the server. Following are my code:

Here is my ServiceGenerator.java code

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String baseUrl)
    {
        Retrofit builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();

        return builder.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Here is My interface class

```
public interface IRetrofit {
    @Headers({

            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @POST("saveRawJSONData")
    Call<JsonObject> postRawJSON(@Body JsonObject jsonObject);
}
```

and my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void onPostClicked(View view){

        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        JsonArray clientsArray = new JsonArray();
        JsonObject clientsObject = new JsonObject();

        clientsObject.addProperty("name", "test");
        clientsObject.addProperty("email", "test@gmail.com");
        clientsObject.addProperty("phoneNumber", "test");


        clientsArray.add(clientsObject);
        jsonObject.add("clients", clientsArray);


        // Using the Retrofit
        IRetrofit jsonPostService = ServiceGenerator.createService(IRetrofit.class, "http://192.168.137.1/originorders/clients/index/");
        Call<JsonObject> call = jsonPostService.postRawJSON(jsonObject);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                try{
                    Log.e("response-success", response.body().toString());
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("response-failure", call.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So what should i do, or have i done something wrong. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you get any thing from HttpLoggingInterceptor ?

Comment: no haven't gotten any respons

Comment: My question may look dumb, but where do you call onPostClicked()?
I suppose your post isn't full code of activity.

Comment: I have called the onPostClicked from the activity_main.xml, android:OnClick... property.

Comment: Did you test try your call with curl? `curl -d '{json}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://example.com`

Comment: i have tried it using Postman, and it works

Comment: @S.Jay can you screenshot how do you send the post request via postman?

Comment: Also make sure that `call.enqueue`(therefore onPostClicked) is called. Since you have logs in both `onResponse` and `onFailure`, there is no way you don't see anything in your logs.

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit's `@Body` annotation automatically serializes data. So, you need to pass body like below.

Create a POJO class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Data {

   @SerializedName("name")
   private String name;
   @SerializedName("email")
   private String email;
   @SerializedName("phoneNumber")
   private String phoneNumber;

   public Data(String name, String email, String phoneNumber) {
      this.name = name;
      this.email = email;
      this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
   }

   // getter and setter methods
}
```

Usage of above class.

In API interface class modify method parameter.

```
Call<JsonObject> postRawJSON(@Body Data data); // from JSONObject to Data
```

And inside `onPostClicked(View view)` method

```
// code
Data d = new Data("test", "test@gmail.com", "9876543210");
Call<JsonObject> call = jsonPostService.postRawJSON(d);
call.enqueue(/* your code implementation here */);
```

Now try to send request (post) to server.

**P.S**: POJO class name can be anything. For demonstration I created `Data`.